# Unity paint circular healthbar dynamically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I got a circular healthbar. It updates, when the current or max life changes.

```
healthBar.fillAmount = currentHealth / maxHealth;
```

So this bar looks boring. There are no borders between the "pieces". When I got eight lifepoints I want to see eight parts there.

Super Mario 64 should be an excellent example

[image: Super Mario 64]

Important would be having small borders showing the lifepoints. Is this even possible?

I don't have 8 lifepoints. The lifepoints are not constant. They are set by the value X. Otherwise I could use a Texture, yes. Furthermore I want to increase the max life in the game, so everything has to work dynamically.

Comment: Perhaps you could try drawing them programmatically, such as with the `GL` library? It'd give you complete control over exactly what is rendered, though it's much less straightforward than the out-of-the-box functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to create a thin line in a graphics editor, import it into Unity as a sprite, then add the sprite as an Image object in your scene.

If you have eight health pieces, you need 4 border lines spaced 45 degrees apart. The code below will clone the image as many times as you need (set via the field pieces, instead of X as you said) and rotate each clone round the z-axis.

```
public GameObject line; //Set your line image via the inspector here
private int pieces = 8;

public void DrawLines()
{
   int linecount = pieces/2;
   float angle = 360 / linecount;

   for(int i = 0; i < linecount; i++)
   {
       GameObject clone = Instantiate(line, Vector3.zero, 
       Quaternion.Euler(0,0,(angle*i)));
   }
}
```